# Automatically provide save file name?

Tags: python, save, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I am a bit new to using the GUI programming application PyQt4 and I had a question about saving files.

Is there some sort of way to create a save file button on a PyQt4 application that doesn't require you to use the `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(...)` function? I want to create a button that will allow you to save files without the user having to enter the name, but rather having it specified based on an already-decided filename that I would provide.

I was trying to look at PyQt4 documentation that could do this but I couldn't find anything that would save files without using the `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(...)` function.

If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: If you already know the filename, why do you need a `QFileDialog`? Couldn't you simply save the file with the Python standard library?

Comment: Hm, is there some sort of built-in Python function to help me save files? If so could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: [See section 7.2](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). I hope this is what you are looking for. If you simply wanted the dialog pre-populated with some name, then it looks like Viktor has answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help Colonel Panic. It really helped! :D I will look through section 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the docs for the [QFileDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName)

You can pass in the exact name of the file:

```
fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save File',
                                             '/path/to/your/file.ext')
```

Comment: Ah, silly me. I guess I wasn't really paying attention. My apologies. Thank you!

Comment: @user1871869 No problem, the API docs are actually not linked anywhere on the PyQt site, which I find really strange :-/, since they are the most useful reference :(

Comment: Ah okay thanks. One last question then--is there a way to save without having the dialog come up since I have already supplied the filename and location of where I want to save my file?

Comment: @user1871869 If you already have a file name just do the thing from Colonel Panic's link `with open(filename, 'wb') as f: f.write(your_data)`